# How to make the content of a dropdown menu part of the parent-element?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

What I want to do:
I have a dropdown menu inside a .slideDown()-div that initially triggers on hover.
The Problem: When the user enters the content of the dropdown menu the div slides up.

So far I figured out that the menu-element is left (hovered out), when the user enters the content of the dropdown menu.

I made this fiddle to illustrate the point of my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/nx70oavr/

Here is the code:

```
<div id="container">
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">          
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
</div>

<div id="info">no action done</div>

$("#container").hover(function() {
    $("#info").text("element entered"); 
}, function() {
    $("#info").text("element left");
});
```

How to make the dropdown-menus content part of its parent? Or prevent triggering the hoverout/mouseout?

Comment: Do not clear what your actual problem and what you want?

Comment: @Stefan - So far it seems like a normal dropdown... can you elaborate?

Comment: Can it be that the drop down menus content is not a child of the container?
The problem is, that that "element left" is triggered when the menus content is entered.

Comment: @Stefan - Yeah its the browsers. I just checked on firefox... there it behaves fine. But Chrome does as you say.

Comment: Oh, you are right. On firefox its as I would expect. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Stefan - I usually end up creating my own controls and monitoring them using jQuery. I can give you an example of a dropdown using css and jquery if you like.

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: @Stefan - Check out this fiddle and tell me if I can make this an answer: https://jsfiddle.net/kyztojv5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with a little bit of jQuery and a little bit of CSS. 
This will only be a reference for you. You can, of course use it and modify it as you like. 
One advantage here is that you control everything, and you can change the colors and everything just as you like to fit you theme. Once you have the logic in place it is quite easy to add even more of your self-created dropdowns.

So here we go:

The HTML:

```
<div class="selectedItem">
    Selected Item: None
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropdownText">Select</span>
    <div class="dropdownGroup">
        <div class="dropdownGroupItem"> Item 1 </div>
        <div class="dropdownGroupItem"> Item 2 </div>
        <div class="dropdownGroupItem"> Item 3 </div>
        <div class="dropdownGroupItem"> Item 4 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 95px; /*Padding makes this 100px in total.*/
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdownGroup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -1px; /*Account for the border and move 1 to the left (2px / 2 = 1px)*/
    width: 100%;
    background: #909090;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.dropdownGroupItem {
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
}

.dropdownGroupItem:hover {
    background: gray; 
}
```

The jQuery(Javascript):

```
var selectedItemText; //Use something like this to save your selected values for later use.
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
    var visibility = $(".dropdownGroup").css("visibility");
    if (visibility == "hidden") {
        $(".dropdownGroup").css("visibility", "visible");
    }       
});

$(".dropdownGroupItem").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //Prevent $(".dropdown").click() from being executed.
    selectedItemText = $(this).text();
    $(".selectedItem").text("Selected Item: " + selectedItemText);
    $(".dropdownText").text(selectedItemText);
    $(".dropdownGroup").css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

I hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

Might be you want this. If I understand you correctly.

```
$("#container select").hover(function() {
    $("#info").text("element entered"); 
}, function() {
    $("#info").text("element left");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nx70oavr/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much, but it has the original bad effect for me in chrome 42.

Comment: What you mean by `bad effect` ?

Comment: When i enter the menus content, the info-div switches to "element left"